# Python: Using dictwriter, but setting value types?

Tags: python, csv, types

I'm just beginning at Python and stackoverflow, forgive me for any mistakes...

I'm trying to use dictreader and dictwriter for a project of mine. Basically I have a dictionary of songs, which contains many keys (names, artists,  play count, song tags for example).

The problem is that when I feed dictwriter into a file, it takes every key and applies the type string to the value.

This isn't a problem for playcount where I can just say int(), but for song tags I have a list of tuples which displays the tag with the amount of times tagged 
For example: [(Rock, 50), (Roll, 50)].

Now when I read this out of my file, row["tags"] has type string... I don't know how to get it to have the appropriate type.

My sort've silly solution which I haven't tried yet is to search through the string for a (, then a ), and append that to a new list, then do it until I've iterated throughout the tags... But it seems like there should be an easier way...

Comment: Wait, are you saying that it literally says "[(Rock, 50), (Roll, 50)]"?

Comment: Essentially! Here's a literal example: "[(u'pop', 100), (u'dance', 85)]" as a str. I want it to be a list of tuples instead of course!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your CSV consists of the representation of basic Python types then you can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert it to Python types.

Comment: ... You do realize I spent forever trying to figure this out, and this is exactly what I was looking for. Words can't express my thanks. Also, it works!

Comment: @Paul: """The problem is that when I feed dictwriter into a file, it takes every key and applies the type string to the value.""" Better would be not to write such files in the first place. Perhaps you should ask another question which shows your code that "feeds dictwriter into a file" and we can help you straighten that out.

Comment: @John: Basically I'm making a playlist generator which takes different algorithms based on song similarity and makes a playlist.  The problem is that to get song tags for a major aspect of similarity, I utilize Last.fm's pylast module to download tags. This takes forever; after downloading the tags, I was trying to keep a local storage of the songs you've downloaded already in a csv file. Thus, the next time you make a playlist with those songs, you could pull from the file. But pulling from the file gave strings, not what I needed! ast.literal_eval() solved the problem

Comment: @Paul: You are missing the point: It's the way that you are writing the CSV file that is causing the problem. Don't do it that way. Nobody else writes CSV files that need ast.literal_eval() to parse then. Seek help.

Comment: @John: Essentially, it's a small part of the project that isn't worth spending a lot of time on. And I recognize that is where the problem is, hence the question I originally asked, but it really doesn't matter since this works anyway and I'm not worried about performance or style for this.  And I was seeking help. Hence I am on Stackoverflow...